# Reportlab and pdfrw with matplotlib imshow() error in python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab, pdfrw

I've recently updated some code which worked in python2 to python3 and encountered an error using reportlab in conjunction with pdfrw and matplotlib imshow().

Can someone reproduce this error in py3? Also I am uncertain whether it is a reportlab issue or a pdfrw problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pdfrw import PdfReader
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10))
plt.savefig('Imshow.pdf')

MyReport = canvas.Canvas('foo.pdf', pagesize=A4)
pages = PdfReader('Imshow.pdf').pages
page = pagexobj(pages[0])
MyReport.saveState()
MyReport.doForm(makerl(MyReport, page))
MyReport.restoreState()
MyReport.save()
```

The error reads

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x1f' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

System:
Windows 10,
Python 3.9,
pdfrw  0.4,
reportlab 3.6.8,

Comment: I'm having the same problem since updating to reportlab 3.6.9. Unfortunately I didn't record which reportlab version I had before. The issue seems to be caused by the binary data in the raster image created by imshow. I suspect the bug is actually in pdfrw. Did you find a solution? If I do, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way pdfrw deals with strings vs bytes.

`pdfrw.PdfReader` loads the entire source PDF using the Latin-1 encoding. All 256 possible byte values are meaningful in Latin-1, so all the binary data in the matplotlib image is loaded. But this creates junk unicode which reportlab is having problems re-encoding (because it doesn't use Latin-1).

The solution is to find data which really should be binary, and pass it to reportlab as correctly-encoded `bytes` instead of `str`. You need to hack the function `_makestr` on line 108 of `pdfrw/toreportlab.py`.

Old, original code (including the TODO tag!):

```
def _makestr(rldoc, pdfobj):
    assert isinstance(pdfobj, (float, int, str)), repr(pdfobj)
    # TODO: Add fix for float like in pdfwriter
    return str(getattr(pdfobj, 'encoded', None) or pdfobj)
```

New:

```
def _makestr(rldoc, pdfobj):
    assert isinstance(pdfobj, (float, int, str)), repr(pdfobj)
    # TODO: Add fix for float like in pdfwriter
    value = str(getattr(pdfobj, 'encoded', None) or pdfobj)
    try:
        value.encode("ascii")  # Don't return this, it is just a test.
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        value = value.encode("Latin-1")
    return value
```

Anything which can't be represented as ASCII is encoded using the original Latin-1 encoding and sent to reportlab as `bytes`.

Based on my testing, this doesn't appear to affect non-ASCII strings in the plot (e.g. axis labels). I guess they go a different way through the pdfrw code - but I don't know!

pdfrw as a project seems to be dead with no release since 2017. If anyone sees this and knows how to contribute a patch to the project, feel free (or let me know).

Comment: I still dont have a solutions for this issue. As a work around I've switched to svglib and generate the imshow as a svg grafik and use it with reportlab. Works good, however the svg files are much larger in size.

Answer (score 0):

Aron Lockey thank. it works!!

def _makestr(rldoc, pdfobj):

```
# --------- Original Code --------------------
# assert isinstance(pdfobj, (float, int, str)), repr(pdfobj)
# # TODO: Add fix for float like in pdfwriter
# return str(getattr(pdfobj, 'encoded', None) or pdfobj)

# --------- New Code --------------------
assert isinstance(pdfobj, (float, int, str)), repr(pdfobj)
# TODO: Add fix for float like in pdfwriter
value = str(getattr(pdfobj, 'encoded', None) or pdfobj)
try:
    value.encode("ascii")  # Don't return this, it is just a test.
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    value = value.encode("Latin-1")
return value
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).